# What is the relationship between the path-loop space fibration and path induction?

Tags: homotopy-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I have an intuition that I can't quite put into words that the path-loop space fibration $\Omega X \rightarrow PX \rightarrow X$ and the based path induction axiom are related, but I don't know enough homotopy theory to formalise it. Can someone formally elaborate this relationship?

Comment: Well, based path induction is more or less the statement that the space $P X$ is contractible (plus some auxiliary facts about contractible spaces). But $\Omega X$ doesn't come into it.

Comment: @ZhenLin thank you you have resolved my confusion post this as an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based path induction is essentially the statement that, for any $x_0 : X$, the type $\sum_{x_1 : X} (x_0 = x_1)$ is contractible. See Theorem 5.8.4 in the *Homotopy type theory* book. The type $(x_0 = x_0)$ does not come into it.